# BigCommerce show account information on new page

Tags: bigcommerce

In BigCommerce (stencil) I have added a new client side page where I would like customers to be able to see all of their orders that are downloadable. However, when I use code from the orders-list.html file, like

```
<ul class="account-list">
    {{#each orders}}
        {{#each items}}
            <li>{{name}}<br/>
                    <a href="{{download_url}}" class="account-product-download button button--primary btn-theme-color">
                        <span class="new-download">{{lang 'account.orders.details.download_items'}}</span>
                    </a>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I show a blank list. The new page doesn't have access to any of the account information, such as past orders. How do I give a new page access to that information? I tried making changes to the manifest.json file and including the new page into any settings where the existing order pages were included, but it didn't work, nothing seemed changed at all.

Comment: It's because bigcommerce have default account information page, why are you making another one, in bigcommerce some page objects work only on particular pages, the objects you used like orders , items are only valid for account page. That's why the pages is coming blank. you can try ajax if you must need to do this.

Comment: @BuggyParadox there are a few reasons I'd like to do this. First so I can have a separate order page to view downloads. Sometimes the files get updated, and when someone wants to download an updated file that they previously purchased, they have to open up each order individually to view the contents and get the download link. 

Secondly, I'd like the product pages to be able to show whether or not someone has already purchased the product they're viewing, as the store gets a lot of accidental double purchases.

Comment: You can make a custom page template for this, it will be available to only logged in users. Use ajax and bring all that data.

Comment: @CodeGator Thank you. Do you know of any good resources on how to do this? I haven't done a lot with ajax and it seems unusually difficult to find answers about anything related to BigCommerce.